How to add an argument to generic function type?
I have a generic function type. I need to convert this type into another, with one more argument prepended to the function:
type FuncType = <T extends any>(arg: T): T;

type FuncWithPrependedArg: ...?

This type should look like this:
type FuncWithPrependedArg = <T extends any>(prepndedArg: any, arg: T): T;

How to derive the second type from the first one dynamically?
I need it because I have an obiect containing different functions and need to create a mapped type for all these functions:
const funcs = {
    funcA: (arg: string): number => {/** ... */},
    funcB: (): string => {/** ... */},
    funcC: <T extends string>(arg: T): T => {/** ... */},
    // ...etc
}

type Funcs: typeof funcs;

type MappedFuncs = SomeTypeToMap<Funcs>;

type SomeTypeToMap = ...?

Is it even possible?

Do you mean something like https://tsplay.dev/w2od4N

You can't manipulate generic function types this way purely at the type level, nor can you do it with a mapped type. The only support for this is with a single higher order function but it can't work on an object of functions. See this playground link for the closest you can get. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
